# How to put images in drawable folder dynamically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-drawable

I will get 5 different images from server that will be in `xxxhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xhdpi`, `hdpi`, `mdpi`. 
The URL will be something like this.

- `http://www.abctest.com/image-xxxhdpi.jpg`
- `http://www.abctest.com/image-hdpi.jpg`

Is there any way i can put these images in drawable folder. So that each device will pickup the image according to its density. I googled but unable to find any way to achieve this.

Or If go to different approach, and get 1 large image from server, then on smaller devices it will create lagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check density of the device by this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
```

and choose image based on the density.
**Edited**
or you can also do this :

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// return 0.75 if it's LDPI  
// return 1.0 if it's MDPI
// return 1.5 if it's HDPI
// return 2.0 if it's XHDPI
// return 3.0 if it's XXHDPI
// return 4.0 if it's XXXHDPI
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way i can put these images in drawable folder.

Not at runtime. Resources and assets are read-only at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, then what should i do? I will be getting `1` or `5`background images from server, If i don;t put them in drawable then i need to create checks for screen density pixels, and based on any checks i will load a different image, or is there any other better way?

Comment: @Kirmani88: "then i need to create checks for screen density pixels, and based on any checks i will load a different image" -- correct. [Chirag shows code for identifying your density](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721489/115145).